# Event when Word 2007 changes the theme

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Is there an event I can register from my VSTO application that is fired when the theme of Word 2007 is changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As crauscher said, Office doesn't seem to trigger any public event when the theme for an Office 2007 application is changed by the user.

The easiest you could do is to poll the registry key at regular intervals to see if there was a change:

```
Office 2007: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\Theme
Office 2010: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Theme
```

Where Theme is `1` for *Blue*, `2` for *Silver* and `3` for the *Black* scheme.

This article gives you some C# code you can use and modify: [Setting the BackColor to match the Office 2007 color scheme](http://blogs.msdn.com/eric_carter/archive/2008/04/11/setting-the-backcolor-to-match-the-office-2007-color-scheme.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d077dddc-a629-41ba-b3d2-e7e957895848/) describes that the theme settings are stored in the registry but not expose through VSTO API.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen an event that does that.

I am only aware of the following Word events, see

[link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/eric_carter/archive/2009/03/24/content-control-event-model-in-word-2007.aspx) also see [Visual studio tools for Office](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=iH-mkXUoeIQC&pg=PA542&lpg=PA542&dq=vsto+word+event-model&source=bl&ots=d_cIi6tDvY&sig=xJ85HILMPWttpl4zKOPB_dAlbTM&hl=en&ei=U9WgSqOoGo2NjAe-4qm3Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4#v=onepage&q=vsto%20word%20event-model&f=false)